# jQuery.ajax() sequential calls

Tags: ajax, jquery

Hey. I need some help with jQuery Ajax calls. In javascript I have to generste ajax calls to the controller, which retrieves a value from the model. I am then checking the value that is returned and making further ajax calls if necessary, say if the value reaches a particular threshold I can stop the ajax calls.

This requires ajax calls that need to be processes one after the other. I tried using `async:false`, but it freezes up the browser and any jQuery changes i make at the frontend are not reflected. Is there any way around this??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should make the next ajax call after the first one has finished like this for example:

```
function getResult(value) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'server/url',
        data: { value: value },
        success: function(data) {
            getResult(data.newValue);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: +1 - For having an answer before I finished that is recursive.

Comment: If the ajax call fails temporarily, success will not get called, and the loop will stop. I'd advise swapping to  complete instead of success to start the loop again

Answer (score 2):

I used array of steps and callback function to continue executing where async started. Works perfect for me.

```
var tasks = [];

for(i=0;i<20;i++){
    tasks.push(i); //can be replaced with list of steps, url and so on
}

var current = 0;

function doAjax(callback) {

    //check to make sure there are more requests to make
    if (current < tasks.length -1 ) {

        var uploadURL ="http://localhost/someSequentialToDo";
        //and 
        var myData = tasks[current];

        current++;

        //make the AJAX request with the given data 
        $.ajax({
            type:     'GET',
            url      : uploadURL,
            data: {index: current},
            dataType : 'json',
            success  : function (serverResponse) {
                doAjax(callback);
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        callback();
        console.log("this is end");
    }
}

function sth(){
    var datum = Date();

    doAjax( function(){
        console.log(datum); //displays time when ajax started
        console.log(Date()); //when ajax finished
    });

}
console.log("start");
sth();
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `success` callback function, just make another `$.ajax` request if necessary. (Setting `async: false` causes the browser to run the request as the same thread as everything else; that's why it freezes up.)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it and let you know

Answer (score 1):

Use a callback function, there are two: `success` and `error`.

From the jQuery `ajax` page:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body,
  success: function(){
    // Do processing, call function for next ajax
  }
});
```

A (very) simplified example:

```
function doAjax() {

    // get url and parameters
    var myurl = /* somethingsomething */;

    $.ajax({
        url: myurl,
        context: document.body,
        success: function(data){
             if(data < threshold) {
                  doAjax();
             }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [$.when()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) (available since 1.5) you can have a single callback that triggers once all calls are made, its cleaner and much more elegant. It ends up looking something like this:

```
$.when($.ajax("/page1.php"), $.ajax("/page2.php")).done(function(a1,  a2){
// a1 and a2 are arguments resolved for the page1 and page2 ajax requests, respectively
    var jqXHR = a1[2]; /* arguments are [ "success", statusText, jqXHR ] */
   alert( jqXHR.responseText )
});
```